# PHP Laravel cURL SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, https, ssl-certificate

I my project written in Laravel I have method that get number value from server:

```
public static function getAddressApiBalance()
    {
        try {
            $uri = "https://btczexplorer.blockhub.info/ext/getbalance/t1ZYiG4R4n5gTgUKZRgVpKPzG5FYQXpEqga";

            $response = Http::get($uri);

            return $response;
...
```

And when I call this code I get error in my browser:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::withOptions([]) accept guzzlet http options
https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify

Comment: Please update this to include more than just a link but additionally how this can be implemented in the context of the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable ssl verification (not recommended!, but quick and easy for dev) :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

or with guzzle :

```
$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);
```

or you can download a cacert.pem file :

```
https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

and edit your php ini with the path of cacert :

```
openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 8 you can use Http API which is easier but still use Guzzle HTTP client behind the scenes. In that case you can disable certificate validation like this:

```
$client = Http::withOptions([
            'debug' => true,
            'verify' => false,
        ])
        ->get('https://btczexplorer.blockhub.info/ext/getbalance/t1ZYiG4R4n5gTgUKZRgVpKPzG5FYQXpEqga', [
            'parameter1' => '1234567',
            'parameter2' =>'890',
        ]);
```

Of course `debug` option is not required to disable ssl checking but it helps with testing. Also `parameters` are just to show how to add them to the request.

Answer (score -2):

You have 3 options to solve that problem (3 way I know) :
1 -> Download certificate file (https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and move it to your php file. Edit your php.ini after it for the cerfificate file.
2 -> Use verify option in your Request to disable ssl verification

```
Http::withOptions([
            'verify' => false,
        ])...
```

3 -> Find Guzzle Client folder to disable ssl for all request
File Locate : **\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php**
Function : **configureDefaults**

```
$defaults = [
            'allow_redirects' => RedirectMiddleware::$defaultSettings,
            'http_errors'     => true,
            'decode_content'  => true,
            'verify'          => app()->env == "local" ? false : true,
            'cookies'         => false,
            'idn_conversion'  => true,
        ];
```

Normally `verify => true` as default. If you edit it only for your local, use it as me or you want to disable it for everything you can use as below.

```
$defaults = [
...
         'verify' => false,
...
]
```

Comment: Never change the contents of the vendor folder